# How to exclude or customize the build timestamp attached to the maven plugin-jar which is built in jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, plugins, pom.xml

I have a eclipse based tool in which I need to specify the name of the jar file as per the description given below -

Suppose the maven plugin id is ***abc.xyz***.
Once the above plugin is built in jenkins:

**Actual:**
*abc.xyz.1.2.3.201909241020.ja*r

**Expected:**
I am looking for any of these solutions:

**1.** abc.xyz.1.2.3.jar

**2.** abc.xyz.1.2.3.custom.jar -> example: abc.xyz.1.2.3.2019.jar

I have tried this but it didn't worked:

**1.** Added "qualifier=none" in the build.properties of abc.xyz plugin

**2.** Tried to call ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} from the plugin pom

Can somebody help me out in this. Thank you

Comment: I guess the following happens: You build an artifact with a version like `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`. When installing/deploying, Maven replaces the `SNAPSHOT` by a timestamp.

Comment: try to change `<finalName>${maven.build.timestamp}.custom.jar</finalName>`